# Why do C++ compilers not forward loads of consts across function calls?

Tags: c++, optimization, language-lawyer

Consider the following example code:

```cpp
void black_box(int* foo);

int foo(int x) {
    black_box(&x);
    return x;
}

int bar(const int x) {
    black_box(const_cast<int*>(&x));
    return x;
}
```

Quoting [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv):

> A const object is
>
> - an object whose type is const-qualified, or
> - [...]
>
> Such object cannot be modified: attempt to do so [..] indirectly (e.g., by modifying the const object through a reference or pointer to non-const type) results in undefined behavior.

The `x` in `bar` is declared const. The compiler should be allowed to assume that `black_box` will not change it. Despite that, the generated x86 assembly for `foo` and `bar` is the same, for both gcc and clang: https://godbolt.org/z/jGsKo56aG

```
push    rax
mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], edi
lea     rdi, [rsp + 4]
call    black_box(int*)@PLT
mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 4]
pop     rcx
ret
```

For `bar`, why does the compiler not move x into a callee saved register, and save the load from memory after the function call?

Comment: Because you SPECIFICALLY removed the `const` attribute.  You told the compiler to do exactly what it did.

Comment: @TimRoberts: my understanding is that `x` is a const-object.
Modifying a const object is undefined behavior.
This should be true, irrespective of any typecasts I do on pointers to x.

Comment: When you use explicit conversions like `const_cast` the compiler assumes that you, as the programmer, really know what you're doing. If you're doing something bad, the compiler will not get into your way, it will happily let you [shoot yourself in your foot](https://mitosystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/LanguageHumor.pdf).

Comment: Also, there's no way for the compiler to know what the `black_box` function is doing, so it can't make any assumptions at all.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: So you're saying that it *could* (by the language specification) optimize this, but implementers chose not to because 'you might be doing something bad'? That seems to go against everything that UB and C++ stands for. I edited in a reference to why I think it's UB btw.

Comment: *irrespective of any typecasts I do on pointers to x* -- No, neither C nor C++ tries to protect you from self-injury.  What do you think the typecasts are for?  Quite seriously, you might actually be happier writing in Rust.

Comment: @TimRoberts OP here is technically right, compiler is allowed to assume that `x` doesn't change and could optimise code based on that... It's just the optimisation OP suggested (saving in callee stored register) doesn't really help, since that still just involves memory store/load anyway, and this isn't exactly a common case you'd want to optimise for.

Comment: The compilers sometimes do that, see https://godbolt.org/z/M4ahY5qe8

Comment: @Cubic: Thank you for acknowledging my point. While it's probably not the highest benefit, saving a few bytes of ICache and helping out the processor's pipeline should be worth something at least, right? Fwiw, not even on `-Os` does the compiler save the instructions.

Comment: @ChrisB you could always raise a patch against gcc to suggest that change. I don't think this would count as a bug because I don't think most people would expect this to be an optimised case. And you'd have to be pretty careful that you only apply this optimisation to cases with const objects, not const references to non-const objects, and even then there may still be some (legally broken, but currently working) code you'd break if you introduced such an optimisation, so you'd have to have arguments ready why you think that's worth it.

Comment: At any rate, the 'why' question here is close to a political issue. You could change the question to ask _if_ a compiler is allowed to optimise that case (yes), but asking "why" particular compiler does or doesn't is not super meaningful and any answer is at least _partially_ going to involve opinion/speculation.

Comment: @Cubic: From my perspective, there are 3 possible answers to the 'why' question: a) There is some reason I'm unaware of why the currently generated code is actually better. b) It's hard to implement this correctly / generally, and the compile time tradeoff / implementation complexity is not worth it.  c) There are too many cases out in the wild were this would cause miscompilation, so it intentionally isn't done. I would love if somebody working on these tools could answer which of the 3 it is, which I think if a fair, technical question and not just 'political'.

Comment: If you have a question that only gcc maintainers are qualified to answer, then you should probably ask it on their mailing list.

Comment: I think it's just because I'm not good at assembly, but it might help if you could post an example of what you would expect the optimized assembly to look like here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For bar, why does the compiler not move x into a callee saved register, and save the load from memory after the function call?

As it so often happens, some ideas sound good until you actually try them.
Thanks to @Brian Bi for prompting me to do just that. As it turns out, compilers are usually pretty good at their job.

If we actually tried what I suggested, we end up with the following assembly:

```
push    rax
mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], edi
lea     rdi, [rsp + 4]
mov     ebx, eax                  ; move `x`(eax) into callee saved register (ebx)
call    black_box(int*)@PLT
mov     eax, ebx                  ; restore `x` into return value register (eax)
pop     rcx
ret
```

While this avoids the load from stack, **it uses an additional instruction**, because the return value has to end up in eax, which gets clobbered by the call. The compiler's version can avoid any additional backup, because they just get the value from the stack. At this point, it is unclear to me whether this would be faster or slower in practice.

The optimal assembly is probably:

```
push    rdi
mov     rdi, rsp
call    black_box(int*)@PLT
pop     rax
ret
```

But compilers have never really been good at these kinds of stack frame layout optimizations.